# convert dictionary to array after removing key values

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

i need to remove first three keys values from each index of array. What i did is

```
  for (int i=0; i<[normalscoringarray count]; i++)        
    { 

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [normalscoringarray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];

        [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"cn"];
        [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"gdate"];
        [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"gid"];

         NSLog(@"mutableDictionary.....%@",mutableDictionary);

     NSMutableArray *remainingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (id item in mutableDictionary) {
            [remainingArray setArray:[mutableDictionary objectForKey:item]];
        }
       }
```

and it does not give remainingArray in that order i want, more over it removes all keys.

```
 normalscoringarray....(
    {
    cn = "Ranjit Garh";
    gdate = "2012-03-25";
    gid = 1;
    id = 1;
    p1nets = "3,3,4,4,2,2,2,4,3,3,4,2,5,3,5,4,3,4||27||33||60";
    p1nh = "BP||14||1";
    p1score = "4,4,5,5,3,3,3,5,4,4,5,3,5,3,6,4,4,5||36||39||75||61";
    p1spoints = "3,3,3,2,3,4,3,3,3,3,2,4,1,2,2,1,3,3||27||21||48";
    p2nets = "4,3,4,4,3,4,2,5,4,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,4,4||33||34||67";
    p2nh = "DG||18||2";
    p2score = "5,4,5,5,4,5,3,6,5,5,4,4,5,4,7,4,5,5||42||43||85||67";
    p2spoints = "2,3,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,3||21||20||41";
    p3nets = "4,3,6,4,2,3,2,4,5,4,3,5,6,3,4,3,5,6||33||39||72";
    p3nh = "NM||24||3";
    p3score = "6,5,7,6,4,5,3,6,6,5,5,6,7,4,5,4,6,7||48||49||97||73";
    p3spoints = "2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,1,2,3,1,0,2,3,2,1,1||21||15||36";
    p4nets = "3,4,5,4,2,3,3,5,3,4,3,5,4,3,5,3,4,6||32||37||69";
    p4nh = "KS||20||4";
    p4score = "5,5,6,5,3,5,4,6,4,5,5,6,5,4,6,4,5,7||43||47||90||70";
    p4spoints = "3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,2,1||22||17||39";
},
    {
    cn = "Eden Garden";
    gdate = "2012-03-26";
    gid = 2;
    id = 2;
    p1nets = "3,2,5,3,1,2,2,4,4,3,4,3,5,2,5,3,3,5||26||33||59";
    p1nh = "NM||24||3";
    p1score = "5,4,6,5,3,4,3,6,5,4,5,4,6,3,6,4,4,6||41||42||83||59";
    p1spoints = "3,4,2,3,4,4,3,3,2,3,2,3,1,3,2,2,3,2||28||21||49";
    p2nets = "2,4,5,3,2,4,3,4,4,4,3,3,5,2,5,3,4,4||31||33||64";
    p2nh = "KS||20||4";
    p2score = "4,5,6,4,3,6,4,5,5,5,4,4,6,3,6,4,5,5||42||42||84||64";
    p2spoints = "4,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,1,3,2,2,2,3||23||21||44";
    p3nets = "3,4,5,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,3,5,6||39||42||81";
    p3nh = "AK||18||5";
    p3score = "4,5,6,6,4,6,5,6,6,6,5,6,6,5,6,4,6,7||48||51||99||81";
    p3spoints = "3,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1||15||12||27";
    p4nets = "2,4,5,4,3,3,3,5,5,4,3,5,4,3,5,4,5,6||34||39||73";
    p4nh = "KR||20||6";
    p4score = "4,5,6,5,4,5,4,6,6,5,4,6,5,4,6,5,6,7||45||48||93||73";
    p4spoints = "4,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,1,1||20||15||35";
},
  )
```

the way i want

```
    normalscoringarray....(
    id = 1,
    p1nets = "3,3,4,4,2,2,2,4,3,3,4,2,5,3,5,4,3,4||27||33||60",
    p1nh = "BP||14||1",
    p1score = "4,4,5,5,3,3,3,5,4,4,5,3,5,3,6,4,4,5||36||39||75||61",
    p1spoints = "3,3,3,2,3,4,3,3,3,3,2,4,1,2,2,1,3,3||27||21||48",
    p2nets = "4,3,4,4,3,4,2,5,4,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,4,4||33||34||67",
    p2nh = "DG||18||2",
    p2score = "5,4,5,5,4,5,3,6,5,5,4,4,5,4,7,4,5,5||42||43||85||67",
    p2spoints = "2,3,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,3||21||20||41",
    p3nets = "4,3,6,4,2,3,2,4,5,4,3,5,6,3,4,3,5,6||33||39||72",
    p3nh = "NM||24||3",
    p3score = "6,5,7,6,4,5,3,6,6,5,5,6,7,4,5,4,6,7||48||49||97||73",
    p3spoints = "2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,1,2,3,1,0,2,3,2,1,1||21||15||36",
    p4nets = "3,4,5,4,2,3,3,5,3,4,3,5,4,3,5,3,4,6||32||37||69";
    p4nh = "KS||20||4";
    p4score = "5,5,6,5,3,5,4,6,4,5,5,6,5,4,6,4,5,7||43||47||90||70",
    p4spoints = "3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,2,1||22||17||39",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *remainingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[normalscoringarray count]; i++)        
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[normalscoringarray objectAtIndex:i]]; //each time alloc and init with contents of normalscoringarray

     //Remove values for keys
    [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"cn"];
    [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"gdate"];
    [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"gid"];

    [remainingArray addObject:mutableDictionary]; //add mutableDictionary to remainingArray

    [mutableDictionary release]; //free mutableDictionary
}

//finally print contents of remainingArray
NSLog(@"normalscoringarray:\n%@",[remainingArray description]);
```

**Hope this would be help you!**

Comment: Also don't forget to release remainingArray when you'll no longer need it.

Comment: Ketan, you asked in your question about the way you wants the result, but I can't understand why do you need it like that format? Because you can access to any values by its key directly.

Comment: actualy i want to apply 'for loop' on every key for checking purpose thats why i need all keys in array...but i am not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<[normalscoringarray count]; i++)        
{       
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[normalscoringarray objectAtIndex:i]];


    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"cn"];
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"gdate"];
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"gid"];

        [normalscoringarray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dictionary];
 }
```